# selecting username using current_user in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I read that the helper current_user can be called in the view. So I have something like this

```
<h1> Customer id <%= User.select(:username).find(current_user).id %> </h1>
```

The equivalent of what I am trying to do in SQL is the following

> SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = current_user

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I'm getting this error message:

> undefined local variable or method `current_user' for
>   ApplicationController:Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the `current_user` available from `Devise`gem, you have access to a `User` instance object, so you can do it directly by:

```
<h1>Customer id <%= current_user.username %></h1>
```

If you want to display the `id`:

```
<h1>Customer id <%= current_user.id %></h1>
```